# Error When sending Email with LargeFileUploadTask

Tags: c#, .net, microsoft-graph-api

I got an error sending an Email via Graph API. I create a draft first and then attach the attachments. I copy / paste the same file 10 times (10mb per file).
The exception is triggered by the call to 'fileUploadTask.UploadAsync'.
It is not always the same file that crashes.  Other file types were successfully sent.

The message size limit is 100mb. The crash is after the 3-4 iteration of the loop

The API Graph gives me an internal error without more explanation.[image]

My Code example:

````
Message draft = await _graphServiceClient
.Users["UserId"]
.MailFolders
.Drafts
.Messages
.Request()
.WithMaxRetry(3)
.WithMaxRetry(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
.AddAsync(message);

foreach (AttachmentRead attachment in emailRead.attachments)
{

    if (attachment.Body.Length < 3)
    {
        FileAttachment fileAttachment = new FileAttachment();
        fileAttachment.Name = attachment.Name;
        fileAttachment.ContentBytes = attachment.Contenu;
        fileAttachment.ContentType = attachment.TypeMime;

        await _graphServiceClient.Users["UserId"].Messages[draft.Id].Attachments.Request().AddAsync(fileAttachment);
    }
    else
    {
        AttachmentItem fichier = new AttachmentItem();
        fichier.Name = attachment.Name;
        fichier.AttachmentType = AttachmentType.File;
        fichier.ContentType = attachment.TypeMime;
        fichier.Size = attachment.Contenu.Length;

        UploadSession uploadSession = await _graphServiceClient.Users["UserId"].Messages[draft.Id].Attachments
                                                                .CreateUploadSession(fichier)
                                                                .Request()
                                                                .PostAsync();
        var maxChunkSize = 1024 * 320;

        using (var stream = new MemoryStream(attachment.Contenu))
        {
            stream.Position = 0;
            LargeFileUploadTask<FileAttachment> fileUploadTask = new LargeFileUploadTask<FileAttachment>(uploadSession, stream, maxChunkSize);

            // upload avec callback
            IProgress<long> progressCallback = new Progress<long>(prog => { });
            try
            {
                   var resultUpload = await fileUploadTask.UploadAsync(progressCallback);
                if (!resultUpload.UploadSucceeded)
                {
                    //Log
                }
            }
            catch (ServiceException e)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
    }

} ```
````

Comment: There is often a limitation to the size of an e-mail (10 MB for some).

Comment: The size limit is 100 mb for the message